# How to imlpement Live RTSP Streaming Android(without using VLC plugin)?

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming, vitamio

I need to stream live videos from my media server using RTSP protocol , (h 264 streaming). The default Android media player shows error while I am trying to stream live videos. The Media player successfully streams the recorded(not live) video using RTSP from the same media server? Is there any way to stream LIVE videos(without using VLC player/plugin)? Is 'Vitamio' multimedia framework meant for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Vitamio will help you. Also you can use  Exoplayer or "[VGX](https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/MediaPlayerSDK/)" player

Comment: So User IJKPlayer